# booleanの切り替え

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

通知機能で過去にチェックをしているか、いないかの確認の為にboolean型のcheckというカラムを通知(Notification)テーブルに入れています。
Notificationコントローラの表示箇所で、checkがfalseの新着通知を開いたらtrueに切り替わるようにしたいのですが、そこでエラーが発生しました。

エラー箇所はNotification_controller.rbのindexのチェックの切り替えを行うコードです。

```
@notifications.where(checked: false).each do |notification|
          notification.update_attribute(checked: true)
        end
```

エラー内容は

```
ArgumentError in NotificationsController#index
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
Extracted source (around line #6):
              
        #通知画面を開くとcheckedをtrueにして通知確認済にする
        @notifications.where(checked: false).each do |notification|
          notification.update_attribute(checked: true)　　　←ここの箇所
        end
    end
```

バージョン
Ruby on Rails6

他に関連するであろうコードがあると思う方は、編集で追記させて頂きますので拝見して頂けたらと思っております。

Answer (score 0):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute

`update_attribute(checked, true)`のように使うのが正しいと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

notification.update_columns(checked: true)でtureに切り替えることが出来ました。